# On click apply toggle functions to parent only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to toggle a disable/enable function for draggable elements, and I'm trying to apply this only to the parent element of the clicked element where the parent element has class `.draggable.`  It works for the toggled class, but how to I pass `(this)` to the functions as well?

```
jQuery("a.check").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
        jQuery(this).hasClass("active") ? disableDrag() : enableDrag();
});

function disableDrag(){
  jQuery(".draggable").draggable("disable");
}
function enableDrag(){
 jQuery(".draggable").draggable("enable");
}
```

Edit - working solution:

```
jQuery("a.check").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
        jQuery(this).hasClass("active") ? disableDrag(this) : enableDrag(this);
});

function disableDrag(obj){
  jQuery(obj).closest('.draggable').draggable("disable")
}
function enableDrag(obj){
jQuery(obj).closest('.draggable').draggable("enable")
}
```

Comment: You mean like `function disableDrag(obj)` & then call it with `disableDrag(this) `

Comment: After that you can use `closest` to find the parent with `draggable` class, so you would have `jQuery(obj).closest('.draggable').draggable("disable")`

Comment: Thanks to both of you, led me to the right track! Got it working now